# Does iOS have something similar to Android's RecyclerView?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` (with a `GridLayoutManager`) that has 4 different view types. In a phone portrait layout, every view type should display 1 item per row. However, one view type (a card) can display two cards per row if the device width is large enough (i.e. tablet).

Does iOS have a similar layout API like `RecyclerView` to allow something this flexible? If so - what is it?

Example (more columns in tablet vs phone)
[image: Example of what I'm trying to achieve.]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use UICollectionView to achieve this

Comment: Thanks. I added an image as an example. Can that still be achieved with a UICollectionView on iOS?

Comment: Yes, other than the watch one

Comment: Make sure to include more detailed information of what and how OP should do it.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, not just similar pattern but it also reuse the views:

```
RecyclerView  -> UICollectionView
Adapter       -> UICollectionViewDataSource
ViewHolder    -> UICollectionViewCell
LayoutManager -> UICollectionViewLayout
```

Answer (score 4):

Several views are currently optimized for performance and resource use, like:

- **`UICollectionView`**
- `UITableView`
- `viewControllers`
- `UIPageViewController`
- `UITabBarController`
- `UIStackView`

You need the **[`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)** that is similar to a Android´s `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use reusable pattern for showing scrollable multi items on screen usually you can use `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`

If you need some custom layout you should take a look into `UICollectionView`