# iOS - Recycling views - the best equilevant to Androids RecyclerView for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm absolutely new to iOS development.

I've seen those answers here:

[Does iOS have something similar to Android's RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227364/does-ios-have-something-similar-to-androids-recyclerview)

but are they up to date? `UICollectionView` is from UIkit and not SwiftUI, should I still use it or is there somewthing better from SwiftUI which is equilevant to Androids RecyclerView?

I will load data with 500 items at once containing images and videos so I don't want to display them all at once but the views need to be "recycled"

The layouts would be like those:

[image]

Comment: Try the provided Lazy Views

Comment: you could search for lazyVGrid and lazyHGrid. here you can found there https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid.    https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhgrid